# Conditional Assignment in Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I came across this code and was hoping someone could help me with it.

I understand that this means that `out` equals to `out_1` if either `a0`, `a1`, `a2`, `a3` is `1`. If not, we have to look at the second expression which is `1'd0`. Any idea what variable does the `1'd0` refer to? Or is this not allowed (I could compile it though).

```
out <= (a0 | a1 | a2 | a3) ? out_1 :
       ( 1'd0 )            ? out_2 :
       (a4 | a5 | a6 | a7) ? out_3 :
       out_4;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confused by this code because the code is a little odd.

You have a compound conditional assignment.  There are 3 conditions: the expressions within parentheses.

You understand how the 1st condition works.  That's great.

The 2nd condition works in a similar fashion: if the condition is true, then assign `out` to `out_2`.  In this case, the condition is a constant, not a variable.  Since the constant has the value 0, the condition will never be true, and `out` will never be assigned to `out_2`.

If the 1st and 2nd conditions are not true, the statement continues with the 3rd condition, etc.

This code can be simplified by removing the 2nd condition:

```
out <= (a0 | a1 | a2 | a3) ? out_1 :
       (a4 | a5 | a6 | a7) ? out_3 :
       out_4;
```

This code will simulate the same way as the code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

It is allowed, but probably a bug in someone's code, or code generator.

To understand this, you need to know that the `?:` has right-to-left associativity (Table 11-2—Operator precedence and associativity in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595)
). It would help to rewrite the code in a more simple manner

```
out = a ? out_1 : 0  ? out_2 : b ? out_3 : out_4;
```

Then put parenthesis in the precedence order

```
out = (a ? out_1 : (0  ? out_2 : (b ? out_3 : out_4))) ;
```

You will see that out_2 can never be selected.

Comment: @ dave_59: Does that mean that out_3 is evaluated first?

Comment: No, associativity and precedence ties certain operands and subexpression to particular operators. The order of evaluation of the operands is indeterminate except as defined by section _11.3.5 Operator expression short circuiting_. If `a` was true _or_ `b` was false, `out_3` would never get evaluated.

Comment: I think I meant to ask 'does that mean the b is evaluated first' .  I think your answer is the same though.  a has priority (goes  first) then b.